# Excel image reference

Tags: excel, image, reference

I'd like to show an image in a cell depending on a chosen value in a list.
In a seperate sheet, i've placed all images into the cells, and set it up that it moves along with the cell.
(I pressed alt to make sure it's linked to that cell).
I've copied one cell (that contains an image), and pasted as linked image.
Now it would be possible to reference it to a cell adress, depending on the chosen value.

Now here's where it fails, when I use 'ADRESS' it errors with 'wrong link'
What am I doing wrong? If I use the same link into a cell it returns '0' which is possible...

This is the formula I use in the linked image formula:
=ADRESS(MATCH(CATKEUZE;B1:B5;0);3)
If i test is, I get a correct cell adress (eg. $C$4)

If I manually fill this in the image formula, it switches the image to the one i've manually directed. So I don't understand why it doesn't work with the formula

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
Don't put the VLOOKUP, or MATCH or whatever in the formula of the picture.
Instead use a dummy cell to obtain the adress.
From that dummy cell use =INDIRECT(dummycell) to use in the formula off the picture.

Also name the **cells** where the images are stored, not the images itselves.